# Regex help for catching all log patterns in a given unix dir?

Tags: java, regex, unix

I have logs in a common landing directory as follows

12345_ABCZ_AA_Loader.20141218.095950941319000.log
   12345_ABCZ_AA_Loader.20141218.095950941319000.log.1
   12345_ABCZ_AA_Loader.20141218.095950941319000.log.2

12345_ABCZ_AA_BB_Loader.20141218.095950941319000.log

and some plain logs as well

SCheckReport.log

I need a regular expression which satisfies both requirements and grabs all logs for todays date.

Thanks

Comment: How about `"."`? It does satisfy all requirements you listed ...

Comment: Wont work as it picks too many files and not limited to just .log files

Comment: that won't part of your requirement ...

Comment: i am looking at log files only as per Original post.

Comment: exactly. So, there is nothing to filter out :) If your requirement is to only match ".log" files, you should have mentioned it in your question. In that case, the regex you are looking for is `\.log` Try to be more clear next time. There are not telepaths here.

Comment: My question has log in its subject and body not sure what you are looking at ?.

Comment: Your question does not mention any other files ... It does not only have log, it also has some letters, and digits, and underscores. How are we supposed to guess, which of those characters you consider significant?

Comment: as per original post "I need a regular expression which satisfies both requirements and grabs all logs for todays date."

Comment: BTW, a question can be put in a million different ways so there is no way i can defend the argument ;).
I forfeit my case Dima

Comment: It's true, that it can be asked in many different ways. But some ways are better than others. The way you asked it was not one of the former. "Satisfies both requirements"? What requirements? There are no requirements at all mentioned in the question, just some sample names. Is it a requirement that the regex matches all the names you mentioned? `\.` satisfies that ... "Today's date"? Where is the date in `SCheckReport.log`? Either way `\.` would definitely "grab all logs for todays date", whatever it is, as long as they are present in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question isn't exactly clear, this would match those Strings:

```
^(.*).log(.\d+)?$
```

EDIT: This doesn't look at todays date, but from your example, one of the filenames doesn't contain a date.

If you want the date, then use:

```
^(.*)20141218(.*).log(.\d+)?$
```

I'll leave it to you to build the regex String from current locale date.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Just to be clear if i needed files from the sample one to be picked for 20141218 what changes would i need to make to your regex (ignore plain sample 2).

Comment: I've edited the post to show the required regex for enforcing presence of the date. Use the 2nd regex statement in the answer. It passes a quick sanity check at RegexPal.